# trying to insert the span just after the li of selected tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

Iam trying to add the element just after the UL > LI having a class

```
$("#div ul li.ui-state-active").insert('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" ></span>');
```

But, I am getting `insert is not a function`, I am sure I am doing something wrong.

want to place the icon just besides the tab which is selected and active

i ahve only used the `active` one, do i also need to use `selected` class

Comment: There are `before`, `after`, `insertBefore`, and `insertAfter` that jQuery offers with regards to inserting elements with relation to another element.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/ & https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/. Given your description I'd suggest `prepend()` or `append()`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

Run snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-info' >I am the new Span</span>").insertAfter("li");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button>Insert span element after li</button>

<div<ul><li></li></ul></div>
```